# Rails - running delayed_job on sh script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have Rails 4.2 running on Unicorn.

I need to call an sh script from my application, but I need my controller to call the SH script and not wait for the SH script to run.

I currently call the sh script with `system(@jobCall)`

For this I installed the delayed_job gem. How do I run the `system(@jobCall)` without waiting for the job to finish?

Full create method code below:

```
  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save

        @jobCall = 'sh /home/some.user/kitchen.sh'
        system(@jobCall) ##need to call this and not wait for job to finish

        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job ran'}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Although not a good solution, you can use `&` and run that processing in background. `@jobCall = 'sh /home/some.user/kitchen.sh &'` Notice `&` at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to run the job in the background [using threads](https://www.agileplannerapp.com/blog/building-agile-planner/rails-background-jobs-in-threads). Although, you may want another way of getting the job result, not render or redirect if you don't need to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ruby / Rails, but just calling system() will not do what you want, because system() does not use the delayed_job gem. Take a look at the [documentation for delayed_job](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/delayed_job/4.1.2).

Basic notion is something like this:

> **Queuing Jobs**
>
> Call .delay.method(params) on any object and it will be processed in the background.
>
> ```
> # without delayed_job
> @user.activate!(@device)
>
> # with delayed_job
> @user.delay.activate!(@device)
> ```

**Edit:**
Not sure whether this works (because I'm lacking any experience with Ruby on Rails), but it should be something like this:

```
class Foo
  def sh_script
    system('sh /home/some.user/kitchen.sh')
  end
  handle_asynchronously :sh_script, :priority => 20
end
```

and then

```
@f = new Foo.new()
@f.delay.sh_script()
```

... should do the trick.

Comment: Right, that's the question though.. where would I chain the .delay ? I tried it on the '@job.delay.save' but that errored out :(

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation it should be chained on whatever method finally executes the shell script. See the edit above.